# After the program executes in Visual Studio community 2015 it shows debug error.

Tags: c++

As soon as I enter the string and press enter the compiler shows debug error and says abort() was encountered. 
What is actually wrong?

```
    #include<iostream>
    #include<string>
    using namespace std;
    int main()
     {   
         std::string str; 
         std::string rev;
         std::cout << "Enter the string\n";
         std::getline(std::cin, str);
         int len = str.size();
         for (int i = len; i > 0; i--)
         {
             std::string temp;
             temp= str.at(i);
             int j = 1;
             rev.insert(j, temp);
             j++;
         }
         std::cout << "The reversed string is\n";
         std::cout << rev;
         cout << "Thank You";
         cin.get();
     }
```

Comment: *What is actually wrong?*  -- What do you think is wrong, given the clear error message you received (and I use Visual Studio to know it didn't just abort() on you without a clear message).

Comment: In order to get most out of StackOverflow, please be precise about your question and provide detailed information about what you've tried so far and how those attempts failed. See the [guidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more information.

Comment: I wanted to upload the screen shot. But since I am new to stackoverflow they didn't allowed me to do it. I need 10 points to do so.

Answer (score 3):

```
 for (int i = len; i > 0; i--)
```

Should be

```
 for (size_t i = len - 1; i >= 0; i--)
              // ^^^         ^
```

The statement

```
 temp= str.at(i);
```

will be out of bounds for the first iteration otherwise.

Indices in c++ are in the `[0 ... (size - 1)]`range.

Comment: `for (int i = len - 1; i >=0; i--)`

Comment: Also size_t would be the better choice here I guess. Or std::reverse.

Comment: @stijn If `size_t` was used it would be an infinite loop.

Comment: Actually, I don't think that would give an out of bounds, considering that is where the null character would be (although AFAIK the null char isn't guaranteed to be there until `c_str` is called). I think the error is that `rev.insert` is being called when it is empty.

Comment: @JamesRoot when using `at` it Throws `std::out_of_range` if `pos >= size()`

Comment: @NathanOliver You're right.

Comment: @NathanOliver oops yes indeed, I was thinking of the original loop and using i - 1 as index; also len - 1 when using size_t is problematic if len is 0..

Answer (score 1):

The earlier answer points out the problems with `str.at (i)`. There's another: on the first iteration it calls `rev.insert (1, ...)`. Since rev has, at that point, a length of zero, that is an out-of-bound access, which will cause an out_of_range exception to be thrown, terminating your program.

Also, move the declaration of j out of the loop. Now it gets recreated with value 1 each time through.

Using an entire string object for tmp seems overkill. Indeed, `rev += str.at(i);` could replace the entire loop body.